# xcode Cocoa App Bad Bundle Executable

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, xcode7, plist

I've been pulling my hair out for hours trying to deploy my Cocoa app to the app store and keep getting the following errors:

- Error ITMS-90236 Missing required icons
- Error ITMS-90260 Bad Bundle Executable
- Error ITMS-90261 Bad CFBundleExecutable

My info.plist file looks like this:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
<string></string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
<string>public.app-category.business</string>
<key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
<string>$(MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)</string>
<key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
<string>Copyright © 2016. All rights reserved.</string>
<key>NSMainNibFile</key>
<string>MainMenu</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string></string>
```

My app icons should load from AppIcon
[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you

Comment: This is an answer but the quick solution is to create a new project and copy all the files.  That was quick and it worked.  The downside was losing the folder organization for the files.

Comment: m facing same issue of bad bundle executable, were u able to solve it

Comment: Sorry, it's been a year since I thought about this.  The error I posted here says I was missing some icons.  I don't know if that was enough to trigger all of these errors, but you are getting something similar, that might be an easy issue to eliminate.